# Add PropTypes (Component - pageProps) to app.jsx in a nextjs app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, eslint, react-proptypes

I am working on a Next.js project and I've added ESLint to it so I've to add PropTypes to each file. Here is the `app.jsx` component where the props are, `Component, pageProps`:

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }) => {
    const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page);
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          {globalStyles}
          {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};
```

The PropType of the `Component` is know but does anyone know how we can define a PropType for `pageProps` knowing that the project is in JavaScript not TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

`pageProps` may change depending of what you are fetching with `getServerSideProps`, `getStaticProps`, and so on.

As per the [NextJs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app):

> pageProps is an object with the initial props that were preloaded for
> your page by one of our data fetching methods, otherwise it's an empty
> object.

```
MyApp.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  pageProps: PropTypes.shape({
    // your custom props here
  }),
};
```